# Create one model from two sets of raw JSON or return multiple models in my view?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

I am making multiple requests to a web API that I've built and it returns raw JSON for each request. Here are the requests:

```
            var client = new WebClient();
            string avgRatesOne = client.DownloadString(urlOne);
            string avgRatesTwo = client.DownloadString(urlTwo);
            var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData.RootObject>(avgRatesOne);
            var modelTwo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyData.RootObject>(avgRatesTwo);

            return View();
```

So how would I be able to make this into one object? Either that or is there a way to access 2 models from my View?

Comment: `var models = new List<RootObject>(new[] { model, modelTwo });` - there you go; one object.

Comment: ^ this is the simplest solution, but assuming the web api controller is in the same app as this code, calling the web api controller from the server side is kind of suspect anyway. (manual serialization is genrally a smell) You may want a layer that both can call.